# SQL Server - Better Way To Join Between VARCHAR and INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for effective way to speed up my query. Let me describe the situation.

Every night, we dump reports from different vendors into a table.  These are a lot of columns, but These columns below are the main columns that I use for joining in the query.

tblVendorShippingInfo (Note that all theses column below are VARCHAR since sometimes reports contains Varchar character even in QtyShipped)

```
PONum     vSKU    vSKUDesc     ShipQuantity
P111111   A       Test1       5
P111111   A       Test1       2
P111111   B       Test3       5
P100002   C       Test4       6
P222222   D       Test5       7
P222222   D       Test5       6
P222222   E       Test6       7
PABC123   F       Test7       8
XYZ123    G       Test8       8
GHEHEH    H       Test9       8
```

tblPODetail -- Our table for Purchase Order. Note that the POID and DistyShippedQty are Integer.  The POID is only 6 digit number.

```
POID      SKU     SKUDesc     DistyShippedQty
111111    A       Test1       
111111    B       Test3       
100002    C       Test4       
222222    D       Test5       
222222    E       Test6
```

If I use the query like this below to get and update the DistyShippedQty, it would work but slow because the conversion... Matching VARCHAR...etc.

```
select POID, SKU
, (
    SELECT SUM(ShipQuantity) AS ShipQuantity 
    FROM tblVendorShippingInfo
    WHERE substring(PONum, 2, 6) = Convert(varchar(10), pod.POID)
    AND vSKU = pod.SKU
    ) AS QtyCount
FROM tblPODetail pod
```

So, I am looking a better way to just filter the records in tblVendorShippingInfo table that only has PONum with 6 digits starting at 2nd position (after P, or any char), ignore all the records with chars (e.g.PABC123, XYZ123, GHEHEH), then index it so it can use for joining with the tblPODetail table.

I attempted to create an indexed view with the filter, but when I run the query with this view, it failed.

```
Alter VIEW vw_tblVendorShippingInfo WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
select dfID, substring(PONum,2, 6) AS POID
, vSKU, ShipQuantity
FROM dbo.tblVendorShippingInfo
WHERE 1 = 1
AND PONum like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to get away with this as an alteration of your `WHERE` clause and have it not be particularly slow: `WHERE PONum LIKE CONCAT('_', pod.POID)`. This way you don't need to join on a substring of PONum and I believe you should be able to use any indexes you have on PONum and POID.

Comment: I tried that and got an error "'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."  I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Hm. `LIKE '_' + CAST(pod.POID AS VARCHAR(10))` would work the same as CONCAT. The issue shouldn't be the conversion but the fact you're joining on a substring of PONum. If it's still slow, then your view solution might be best.

Comment: Does this make a difference? `WHERE CONVERT(int, substring(PONum, 2, 6)) = pod.POID`

Comment: I tried "WHERE CONVERT(int, substring(PONum, 2, 6)) = pod.POID" and it didn't work.  The problem is PONum is inconsist, sometime the value is "XYZ12345", then it will fail for the conversion.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.  You just need the right expression for `like`:

```
SELECT POID, SKU,
       (SELECT SUM(ShipQuantity) AS ShipQuantity 
        FROM tblVendorShippingInfo vsi
        WHERE substring(vsi.PONum, 2, 6) = Convert(varchar(10), pod.POID) AND
              vSKU = pod.SKU
       ) as QtyCount
FROM tblPODetail pod 
WHERE PONum like '[A-Za-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

If you want to index this as an integer, then use a computed column:

```
alter table tblVendorShippingInfo add column POID_num as try_convert(int, substring(PONum, 2, 6);

create index idx_tblVendorShippingInfo_POID on tblVendorShippingInfo(POID_num);
```

`try_convert()` assumes SQL Server 2012+.  You can do something similar with earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: I think you solution is best, but I am still struggling to figure out.  Regarding to the first one about the right expression, can it be LIKE only character from position 2 to 7, but also NOT include anything if it contains letter (A-Z).  For example, It would capture records with 6 digits for string like "P123455, Z334545H, 9222222KK", but ignore string like "AB12345689, 12345Z6" since position 2-7 contains letter.  Thank you

Comment: I also like your 2nd solution about computed column, but still not able to figure it out either.  I am using SQL Server 2008, no try_convert() option, can computed column work for the criteria I described above -- Only 6 digits from position 2-7 and ignore any contains letter (A-Z)?

Comment: I tried to create the computed column like this, but not working ""Alter table tblVendorShippingInfo add POID as (Substring(PONum,2, 6)  NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')""

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I was able to add a computed column with index by using Function with SCHEMABINDING.

Answer (score 0):

If it's Oracle (and maybe others) you can specify an index on a virtual/computed by column.

Alternatively add a column and populate it once during the nightly upload.